# has_many doesn't fetch all when includes(:association).where("association.something = ?", value)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, has-many

I need your help:

I have Three Models:

Phonogram has_many PhonogramInstrument:

```
class Phonogram < ActiveRecord::Base
  #... things
  has_many :phonogram_instruments, source: :filter, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :phonogram
  has_many :instruments, source: :filter, through: :phonogram_instruments
end
```

PhonogramInstrument belongs_to Filter:

```
class PhonogramInstrument < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :phonogram
  belongs_to :filter
end
```

and Filter:

```
class Filter < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

So, I need to fetch all phonograms that have filter_id 30 for example:

```
@phonograms = @phonograms.includes(:phonogram_instruments).where("phonogram_instruments.filter_id = ?", 30)
```

That fetches me one list with one object (exactly what I was expected):

```
=> [#<Phonogram id: 14, title: "Test", version_title: "", notes: nil, isrc: "BR3BD1300003", release_date: "2013-02-01", created_at: "2014-02-23 16:54:24", updated_at: "2014-08-27 03:19:08">]
```

...but if I take this object and show its instrument:

```
    @phonograms.first.phonogram_instruments.inspect
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<PhonogramInstrument id: 51, phonogram_id: 14, filter_id: 30, created_at: "2014-08-27 07:01:27", updated_at: "2014-08-27 07:01:27">]>
```

but at this phonogram I have 7 PhonogramInstruments:

```
 Phonogram.find(14).phonogram_instruments.inspect
=> "#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [
#<PhonogramInstrument id: 25, phonogram_id: 14, filter_id: 25, created_at: \"2014-06-04 06:11:14\", updated_at: \"2014-06-04 06:11:14\">, 
#<PhonogramInstrument id: 26, phonogram_id: 14, filter_id: 26, created_at: \"2014-06-04 06:11:14\", updated_at: \"2014-06-04 06:11:14\">, 
#<PhonogramInstrument id: 48, phonogram_id: 14, filter_id: 49, created_at: \"2014-08-27 03:19:07\", updated_at: \"2014-08-27 03:19:07\">, 
#<PhonogramInstrument id: 49, phonogram_id: 14, filter_id: 50, created_at: \"2014-08-27 03:19:08\", updated_at: \"2014-08-27 03:19:08\">, 
#<PhonogramInstrument id: 50, phonogram_id: 14, filter_id: 29, created_at: \"2014-08-27 07:01:27\", updated_at: \"2014-08-27 07:01:27\">,
#<PhonogramInstrument id: 51, phonogram_id: 14, filter_id: 30, created_at: \"2014-08-27 07:01:27\", updated_at: \"2014-08-27 07:01:27\">, 
#<PhonogramInstrument id: 52, phonogram_id: 14, filter_id: 31, created_at: \"2014-08-27 07:01:27\", updated_at: \"2014-08-27 07:01:27\">
]>"
```

Help please! :)

Comment: There is only one PhonogramInstrument matches the condition of phonogram_id 14 and filter_id 30, so ilrein's answer was right.

Comment: But the phonogram #14 has 7 PhonogramInstrument, and the where brings me ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy with my phonogram #14 with 1 PhonogramInstrument

Comment: Can you execute your code `@phonograms.includes(:phonogram_instruments).where("phonogram_instruments.filter_id = ?", 30)` in rails controller? And run the SQL generated by rails on your database command window. You could post the SQL and the result on your question.

Answer (score 4):

Try `joins` instead of `includes`:

```
  @phonograms = Phonogram.joins(:phonogram_instruments).where("phonogram_instruments.filter_id = ?", 30)
```

see section on preload here

http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Comment: I tried. I had an error because the previous @phonograms was including other associations

Answer (score 2):

You didn't explicitly ask a question. What is the problem? I see you are indicating that Phonogram # 14 has 7 objects associated to it, while Phonogram # 1 has 1 object associated to it (where the filter ID is set to 30).

Everything seems to be going as expected...

Comment: Both phonogram objects is the same #14

Answer (score 0):

Done!

My error was because my previous list was including other association with includes():

```
@phonograms = @phonograms.includes([:artists, :partners, :labels, :albums]).where(...)
```

When I tried to use

```
@phonograms.joins("phonogram_instruments").where(...)
```

...I got an error near the word "phonogram_instruments" floating alone on my query.

So, I put manual LEFT OUTER JOIN on my query:

```
@phonograms = @phonograms.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN \"#{listed_filter.type}\" \"#{listed_filter.type}_phonograms\" ON \"#{listed_filter.type}_phonograms\".\"phonogram_id\" = \"phonograms\".\"id\"").where("#{listed_filter.type}_phonograms.filter_id = ?", listed_filter.id)
```

It works! Thanks all!